# проблемы с установкой react app и eslint

Tags: reactjs, npm

При установке находит уязвимости. Локализация русская, возможно в ней дело. Меняла
имя пользователя на английское и пыталась ставить в другие разделы и директории. Ноду переустановила. Может кто подскажет идеи, что ещё может быть? Сносить винду и ставить английскую или хватит языкового пакета?

При запуске npm audit fix ничего само не устраняется.

```
H:\front study\float\final-project\marvel-app>npm install eslint --save-dev
    npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.14.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    
    + eslint@7.28.0
    updated 1 package and audited 1930 packages in 35.002s
    
    138 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    
    found 86 vulnerabilities (82 moderate, 4 high)
      run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Вот что выдала консоль при установке реакта

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall H:\front study\float\marvel-project\marvel-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.14.0 postinstall H:\front study\float\marvel-project\marvel-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.14.0 postinstall H:\front study\float\marvel-project\marvel-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall H:\front study\float\marvel-project\marvel-app\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

+ cra-template@1.1.2
+ react@17.0.2
+ react-dom@17.0.2
+ react-scripts@4.0.3
added 1898 packages from 703 contributors and audited 1901 packages in 206.925s

145 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 8 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.14.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ web-vitals@1.1.2
+ @testing-library/react@11.2.7
+ @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
+ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.14.1
added 29 packages from 78 contributors and audited 1930 packages in 19.481s

145 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 8 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.14.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

removed 1 package and audited 1929 packages in 11.886s

145 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 8 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: попробуйте удалить package-lock.json, и eslint лучше устанавливать в -D

Comment: Пробовала(
Ничего из этого не сработало

Comment: так а что за ошибка была при установке?

Comment: Добавила в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Это должно помочь

```
npm cache clean -f
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]